# как увеличивать растояние каждой следующей карточки используя scss

Tags: css3, scss

можно ли увеличить left свойства каждой последующей карточки на 10px использую только scss? например первой карточки будет left: 0; второй: left: 10px; третьей 20px и тд

html

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="card">1</div>
    <div class="card">2</div>
    <div class="card">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать цикл:

```
@for $i from 0 through 2 {
  .wrapper .card:nth-child(#{$i+1}) { left: 10px*$i; }
}
```

[Воспроизводимый пример на codepen](https://codepen.io/Humster_Spb/pen/vMdgOd)